# Classification Error in Watson Conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

This morning all of my code that uses Watson Conversation suddenly stopped working. I get this error in the console:

> { Error: Classification Error: Protocol error
>
> at Request._callback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\watson-developer-cloud\lib\requestwrapper.js:99:21)
>
> at Request.self.callback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
>
> at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>
> at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
>
> at Request. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:1163:10)
>
> at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>
> at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
>
> at Gunzip. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\request\request.js:1085:12)
>
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
>
> at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>
> code: 500,
>
> error: 'Classification Error: Protocol error',
>
> 'x-global-transaction-id': '7ecac92c5aa8813805dfb888' }

I did not change any of my code recently. So I assumed it must be a problem with IBM Watson, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It seems to be an outage of the Watson Conversation service.

https://console.bluemix.net/status/notification/ae744d684432a9086528e8c9a4c21033

> Users of the Watson Conversation service are experiencing elevated error rates when attempting to use the service. The team is aware and is working to resolve.
>
> 2018-03-14 0148 UTC: Added United Kingdom and Sydney regions to affected list.

**Update**: it keeps happening occasionally, I've even written code to retry automatically a few times, but it doesn't help. Seems the Watson service is simply down for a couple of minutes at a time.

**Update**: happening again on December 10, 2018.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm getting the exact same error: 

{
    "error": "Classification Error: Protocol error",
    "code": 500
}

Everything was working fine last night and now no more. I've been banging my head on the wall trying to figure out where did I mess-up the code. Turns out I DIDN'T!!!